# Не получается собрать образ docker

Tags: docker, devops

Прохожу введение по docker: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#dockerfile).

Пытаюсь собрать образ docker, имеется 3 файла:

- dockerfile;
- requirements.txt;
- app.py;

Содержимое dockerfile:

```
#Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Содержимое requirements:

```
Flask
Redis
```

Содеежимое app:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

При попытки установить библиотеки Flask и Redis для Python командой 
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Выдает:

`pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install -r requirements.txt
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Теперь проблема следующая:
При команде `docker build --tag=friendlyhello .`.Выдает ошибку :

> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\docker\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: А вы pip и / или собственно питон предварительно поставили? Какой у вас докерфайл?

Comment: Питон установлен, "Какой у вас докер-файл" подразумевается что внутри него ? (Все команды выполняю в powershell)

Comment: Конечно. Надо было его содержимое сразу привести. Особенно ту часть, где вы ставите питоон (ну или откуда он там у вас в образе берется), а то "Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета" намекает, что питон не установлен.

Comment: Теперь не создается образ сборки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу - установите `pip` именно в контейнере:

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt python-pip
```

Это на случай, если ваш образ стороится на Ubuntu. Если нет - надо использоваться соответсвующий пакетный менеджер.

> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\docker\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.

Проверьте, что `Dockerfile` находится в текущей директории. Причем файл называться должен именно так - с заглавной буквы.

Если файл называется по другому - можно так:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello -f ./Dockerfile.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете еще попробовать прописать полный путь к Dockerfile

```
docker build -t friendlyhello "D:\project1"
```

где project1 - папка с Dockerfile